# How to drawn my own progressbar on winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, colors, progress-bar

Yoyo experts!
I have several progressbars on my Windowsform (NOT WPF), and I would like to use different colors for each one.
How can I do this? I've googled , and found that I have to create my own control. But I have no clue , how to do this. Any idea? For example progressBar1 green, progressbar2 red.

Edit: ohh, I would like to solve this, without removing the Application.EnableVisualStyles();
line, because it will screw my form looking up :/

Comment: Yes, its Winform. I cant move to WPF, thats for sure.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778678/how-to-change-the-color-of-progressbar-in-c-net-3-5

Comment: @Mark Byers Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, create your own.  A rough draft to get you 80% there, embellish as needed:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyProgressBar : Control {
    public MyProgressBar() {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        Maximum = 100;
        this.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    public decimal Minimum { get; set; }  // fix: call Invalidate in setter
    public decimal Maximum { get; set; }  // fix as above

    private decimal mValue;
    public decimal Value {
        get { return mValue; }
        set { mValue = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        var rc = new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)(this.Width * (Value - Minimum) / Maximum), this.Height);
        using (var br = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor)) {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rc);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, BUT I cant access my designer, now :(
To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:
An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2, position 97.