# How to modify and use XAML ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar, controls

In a series of posts here, it was explained how to inherit and override behavior in the XAML ProgressBar here:
[How to change the color of progressbar in C# .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778678/how-to-change-the-color-of-progressbar-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

I must be doing something wrong.  I tried to post a question or comment there, but since I'm new wasn't allowed (and that being incomprehensible to me is likely further proof of my noob-ism).

The code does not build-- it is\s missing the usings.  That wouldn't seem to hard to figure out but... I made best guesses at these, but encountered complex namespace issues- Windows.Controls or Windows.Forms.

Plus, how do you actually use such a modified control?  It seems you might say local:ProgressBarEx in your XAML.

A complete example that does this sure would be nice to see.

Comment: Adding a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will help other people help you.  As it is this question will be difficult to answer without additional information.

Comment: The link you refer to is a Windows Forms example not a WPF example and isn't relevant.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Post a question about what you need instead of asking about some one else's answer which you can't comprehend.