# WinForms ProgressBar - Remove Border and Background

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, controls

I am trying to modify the appearance of a WinForms progress bar by flattening the appearance of the bar, and removing the background and border. I was able to flatten the bar using this example I found elseware: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5622633/663604. My code look almost exactly like the answer I just linked to.

However, I cannot seem to find a way to visually remove the background and border of the progress bar:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186238/EasyProgressBar-for-Windows-Forms-Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to remove the border for sure. You will have to create your own custom progress bar. You can find a good help here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323116

Comment: Thank you! I rolled my own by extending the `Control` class.

Comment: Using ProgressBarRenderer in a custom control, this provided me the direction of how to deal with the default border on the progress bar. Thanks!!