# Changing the color of a progressbar in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Im using: Visual Studio 2013 (Visual Basic) >>NOT<< C# :)

So, I am making a program which is checking how much space you have on a harddrive, so, when there is less then 20% memory, I want the progressbar change its color to red, usually it is green, so I hope this is possible, thankyou so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the color of progressbar in C# .NET 3.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778678/how-to-change-the-color-of-progressbar-in-c-sharp-net-3-5)

Comment: Look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335455%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ...

Comment: @AlexanderFalkesund I'd agree that it's not a duplicate (due to it being the wrong language), however, anything that's possible in C# is usually translatable fairly easily into VB (and vice versa).  Take a look at the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9753302/791010) - looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `SendMessage`:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
```

And use this function:

```
SendMessage(ProgressBar1.Handle, 1040, 2, 0)
```

Color codes:

```
1: green
2: red
3: yellow
```

Comment: And where in the code should I put the color codes?

Comment: Third parameter is an integer, that sets the color, apparently only these three colors are available.