# Change (custom) ProgressBar color

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, progress-bar, pinvoke

I'm creating a custom progress bar with a property

```
Public Class CustomProgressBar : Inherits ProgressBar

    Private _State As ProgressStates

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lParam As String) As Int32
    End Function

    <Category("Appearance")> _
    <DefaultValue(ProgressStates.Normal)> _
    <Description("The progress state, Red=Error, Yellow=Warning, Green=Normal")> _
    Public Property State As ProgressStates
        Get
            Return _State
        End Get
        Set(value As ProgressStates)
            _State = value
            SendMessage(MyBase.Handle, 1040, value, 0)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

ProgressStates

```
Public Enum ProgressStates

    Normal = 1
    [Error] = 2
    Warning = 3

End Enum
```

In the designer I set my custom property to `Error` and it works fine (in the designer), but when I run my application, progress value sets automatically to 0 and property is not applied

[image: Designer and executable]

Comment: The way in which you are using `SendMessage` is unnecessarily confusing. You should better rely on the constant name which is expected to be used here, that is: `PBM_SETSTATE` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760850(v=vs.85).aspx). Also, it would be clearer to use the usual format for `IntPtr`, that is: rather than `1040`, `&H400 + 16`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Property exactly, but the [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html) is imperfect either in the source or your conversion.  I suspect you started with [this old C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753302/1070452).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=False)>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr,
                                        Msg As UInt32,
                                        w As IntPtr,
                                        l As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Const PBM_SETSTATE = &H400 + 16
    Friend Enum PBMStates
        Normal = 1
        [Error] = 2
        Paused = 3
    End Enum

    Friend Shared Sub SetProgressState(ctl As ProgressBar, state As PBMStates)
        SendMessage(ctl.Handle, PBM_SETSTATE, New IntPtr(state), IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub
End Class
```

According to the MSDN docs, `PBM_SETSTATE` returns the previous state.  I've ignored that and made it a Sub.  Since it only is supposed to be used with a `ProgressBar` I it to accept only a `ProgressBar` control rather than a control handle (which could be from any control). Finally, the code is `Shared` and in a `NativeMethods` class so CA will not complain. Usage:

```
NativeMethods.SetProgressState(ProgressBar1, NativeMethods.PBMStates.Error)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I believe the trouble is calling to sendmessage before load the form, because I tried to use the snippet on `Load` event of form and it worked correctly, but when I send the message in my custom control, it is applied before load, Is there some override sub like `onCreateControl()`, but after form load?

Comment: You cant call it before the form loads - there is no handle for it before that.  Is it a UserControl?  *In* the load event should work

Comment: I just tested it in Form Load and after it has been shown and it works fine both places.  More info would be needed on what the control is etc

Comment: ----------------ENDING COMMENT CONVERSATION AND START ANOTHER ONE---------------------------------------

Comment: The problem is not the property, the problem is the moment that sendmessage is invoked because progress animation has to end before send a message SETSTATE

Comment: The color wont change until it stops animating (and only Green animates), but once it finishes, the state changes - windows stacks up messages, it doesnt throw them away.  The *original* problem - the value being goofed up - was a result of the bad PInvoke.  Are you calling this in very rapid succession, constantly changing the state?

Comment: Is there some overrides sub like this "onAnimationEnd()"? If I set the progress value before calling to my property, it not works

Comment: I just did that in a loop and the color wont change until it is done (too many paints too often), but when it is done, the state is set.  Again, `Are you calling this in very rapid succession`? and what does "it not works" mean?  is it throwing away the value like originally?