# Circular progress bar in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm searching for an circular progress indication for Inno Setup, like this one on jQuery: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

[image]

Is there something similar or is it possible to do this in Inno Setup?

I want to set the percentage manually, it shouldn't be a spinning circle or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Without an external DLL library, all you can do is to use [`TBitmapImage` control](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TBitmapImage) and draw the progress bar manually.

For an example of painting on `TBitmapImage`, see [How do I change the color of my progress bar in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33630532/850848)

---

An easier option is to prepare set of progress images (10%, 20%, 30%, etc) in advance and load respective image as needed.

Comment: Umm...Thanks for the answer...I made this code...Can you correct it & make it compatible for progress bar...
`type
  HDC = LongWord;

function SetBkMode(DC: HDC; BkMode: Integer): Integer; external 'SetBkMode@gdi32.dll stdcall';

procedure WizardFormOnPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TWizardForm(Sender).Canvas do
  begin
    Pen.Color := clBlack;
    Pen.Width := 1;
    Arc(0,0,ScaleX(200),ScaleY(200),ScaleY(LabelPct1 * 1000000),0,0,0);
  end;
end;`

Comment: There's no `OnPaint` in Inno Setup. Please follow the approach from the linked answer.