# Converting ARGB to Hex

Tags: c#, .net, rgb

I am trying to make a color changing mehapps metroui progress bar based on the percentage of the file that is downloaded. In lua I do like so:

```
ARGB(255, 255 * percent, 255 - (255 * percent), 0)
```

Now in trying to do this in C#:

```
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    label2.Content = "Downloaded " + (e.BytesReceived / 1000) + "kb" + " of " + (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1000) + "kb" + " (" + Math.Round(percentage) + "%)";
    progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255 * (Math.Round(percentage)), 255 - (255 * (Math.Round(percentage))), 0);
    string hex = myColor.R.ToString("X2") + myColor.G.ToString("X2") + myColor.B.ToString("X2");
    Console.WriteLine(hex);
}
```

The label2 works great but the mycolor line errors out with:

> Cannot convert from double to byte.

I even tried using `progressBar1.Value` and get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to just make my progress bar go from red to green based on percentage downloaded?

Comment: By the way, please just cast those ints to doubles, don't convert them to string and then parse them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778678/how-to-change-the-color-of-progressbar-in-c-sharp-net-3-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This whole thing can be much simpler.

```
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label2.Content = string.Format("Downloaded {0}kb of {1}kb ({2}%)", e.BytesReceived / 1000, e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1000, e.ProgressPercentage);
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    int c = e.ProgressPercentage * 255 / 100;
    // unused, but this would be how you'd get it
    // Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)(255 - c), (byte)c, 0);
    string hex = string.Format("FF{0:X2}{1:X2}00", 255 - c, c);
    Console.WriteLine(hex);
}
```

What I've done here:

- use `e.ProgressPercentage` in most places.
- avoid doubles entirely by scaling the colour as an integer (avoiding `Round` all over the place). Note the order of the multiplication and the division.
- used `string.Format`
- cast to byte, avoid `Convert`

By the way, this interpolates between red and green linearly, meaning it goes through murky dark yellow in the middle, instead of actual yellow. In order to go through yellow, you could use something like

```
int s = e.ProgressPercentage * 255 / 50;
int r = Math.Min(255, 510 - s);
int g = Math.Min(255, s);
```

Then proceed in the obvious way.

edit: swapped red/green as resquested.

Comment: This is totally simpler and easy to understand.

Comment: Og course, with C# 6 (which everyone should be using, as it's so much better than previous versions ;), the 1`string.Format` line can be changed to `string hex = $"FF{c:X2}{255-c:X2}00";`

Comment: Ok i tried for an hour to figure out how to do this on my own but I cant and im sure its simple, what you posted works great except it goes from green to red and I need it to go from red to green, how can I invert it?

Comment: @loveroflua didn't your original code do that as well? I tried to make it the same. Anyway just swap the red and green then, no big deal. I'll edit it in though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the problematic line to

```
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Convert.ToByte(255 * Math.Round(percentage/100)), 255 - Convert.ToByte(255 * (Math.Round(percentage/100))), 0);
```

You have to divide `percentage` by 100 in order to get value from 0 to 1 and then cast the result to byte, since method `Color.FromArg()` expects byte parameters.

Comment: Cannot convert int to byte now

Comment: Did you divide "percentage"?

Comment: Is type of percentage  double or int?

Comment: You realize you're now rounding a double that is in [0,1] right?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255 * (Math.Round(percentage)), 255 - (255 * (Math.Round(percentage))), 0);
```

To

```
Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255 * (Math.Round(percentage / 100)), 255 - (255 * (Math.Round(percentage / 100))), 0);
```