# How to fill panel background color based on dynamic value

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am working on an desktop application in C# that requires a panel background to be filled using dynamic values.For example if the panel of width 200px and the progress property is currently reached at 50% then 100px of the panel should have green color in it rest 100px will be as it.

Comment: I did try difference panel_paint event but with no luck

Comment: Surely using a ProgressBar would be easier (Aero knows what progressbars are , so it will animate it suitably etc)? If you're desperate to roll your own wouldn't get into painting myown rectangle; I'd just add another panel inside the first one, docked to the left and width = 200 * 50/100, make the backcolour of the new panel green, and change its width as progress occurs

Comment: _I did try difference panel_paint event but with no luck_ What are we to make of that? Paint is the right event; show your code!!! You trigger it from whereever the progress is made or noted by calling panel.Invalidate(). You fill a rectangles with e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green) and set the Backcolor to Color.Red. Do DoubleBuffer the Panel!! - Or use Caius' advice if using two panels!

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually i did tried your idea about using the progress bar but unfortunately using progress bar comes with its own challenges of using different colors in that. Though panel inside panel is i am going to try.

Comment: We have to see your paint code in order to help you.

Comment: Create the green rectangle at design time. Make it invisible. When the time is right, make it visible. I would look for a progress bar that can have a gradient color and play with the gradient.

Comment: @NitinSingh color your own progress bar (but read all answers-accepted answer might not be what you want): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778678/how-to-change-the-color-of-progressbar-in-c-sharp-net-3-5 - remember that choosing the user's colors *is not your job*; the user has picked the windows theme they want, including the color of the progress bar they want. You might pick a color they cant see well.. I still recommend you just use progressbar and if you want it green, set your Windows to green theme, but leave my Windows' blue progressbars blue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a simple control that does the job

```
public partial class ProgressPanel : Panel
{
    private float m_progress = 0;
    private Color m_progressColor = Color.Green;
    public ProgressPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the progress value is between 0 & 100 inclusively
    /// </summary>
    public float Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return m_progress;
        }
        set
        {
            m_progress = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color ProgressColor
    {
        get
        {
            return m_progressColor;
        }
        set
        {
            m_progressColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void ProgressPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(ProgressColor), new Rectangle(new Point(), new Size((int)(Width * Progress / 100), Height)));
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // ProgressPanel
        // 
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.ProgressPanel_Paint);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

just create a new empty class in your project & name it `ProgressPanel` then copy the above code into it.

now you can use your newly created `ProgressPanel` as you would use any other control from the designer

note that this example is a simplified one.
you may notice some flickering, but other than this it's totally functional

if you want to know how to upgrade this example to a professional control, I'd be happy to help

Comment: sorry for the mistake, but I've fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks Man. Yes indeed i had to change the constructor with public but that did work like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: don't forget to also change this line
`e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(ProgressColor), new Rectangle(new Point(), new Size((int)(Width * Progress / 100), Height)));`

Comment: @NitinSingh You should be disposing that brush you are creating.

Comment: the compiler is smart enough to automatically dispose it as soon as you don't need it anymore