# Add static method to current custom class

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have custom progress bar (is a progress bar with text)

Custom progressbar code:

```
public enum ProgressBarDisplayText
    {
        Percentage,
        CustomText
    }

    public class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {


        [DllImportAttribute("uxtheme.dll")]
        private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "", "");
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        }

        //Property to set to decide whether to print a % or Text
        public ProgressBarDisplayText DisplayStyle { get; set; }

        //Property to hold the custom text
        public String CustomText { get; set; }

        public CustomProgressBar()
        {
            // Modify the ControlStyles flags
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(g, rect);
            rect.Inflate(-3, -3);
            if (Value > 0)
            {
                // As we doing this ourselves we need to draw the chunks on the progress bar
                Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, (int)Math.Round(((float)Value / Maximum) * rect.Width), rect.Height);
                ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks(g, clip);
            }

            // Set the Display text (Either a % amount or our custom text
            int percent = (int)(((double)this.Value / (double)this.Maximum) * 100);
            string text = DisplayStyle == ProgressBarDisplayText.Percentage ? percent.ToString() + '%' : CustomText;

            //string text = DisplayStyle == ProgressBarDisplayText.Percentage ? Value.ToString() + '%' : CustomText;


            using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold))
            {

                SizeF len = g.MeasureString(text, f);
                // Calculate the location of the text (the middle of progress bar)
                // Point location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32((rect.Width / 2) - (len.Width / 2)), Convert.ToInt32((rect.Height / 2) - (len.Height / 2)));
                Point location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32((Width / 2) - len.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32((Height / 2) - len.Height / 2));
                // The commented-out code will centre the text into the highlighted area only. This will centre the text regardless of the highlighted area.
                // Draw the custom text
                g.DrawString(text, f, Brushes.Black, location);
            }

        }
    }
```

Now I want to change color of progress bar so I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753302/13084319)

So I try to add to my code

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
  static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr w, IntPtr l);
    public static void SetState(this ProgressBar pBar, int state)
    {
        SendMessage(pBar.Handle, 1040, (IntPtr)state, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

But as you can see this code is for an extension method, but my current `CustomProgressBar` inherits `ProgressBar` and it does not permit to use static classes. So it throw me:

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

how can I add this method to my current class? Regards

Comment: Extension methods must be defined in a `static` class. Normally I just create a `public static class Extensions { }` and add them there. If you want to add them to your current class, you can just remove `this` from the first argument and then pass in an instance of your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an extension method and those need to go in a static class. If you want to just make it work in your existing non-static class, just get rid of the `this` on the first parameter:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr w, IntPtr l);

public static void SetState(ProgressBar pBar, int state)
{
    SendMessage(pBar.Handle, 1040, (IntPtr)state, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

The parameter can still be of type `ProgressBar` since `CustomProgressBar` inherits from it.

Comment: I copy paste your code and it works but I don't understand why? What do you mean when you say get rid of `this`, I see your code same as mine, what is the difference?

Comment: Yours has `this ProgressBar pBar` and mine just has `ProgressBar pBar`.