# Prevent flickering of custom ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, progress-bar, gdi+

For the app I'm making, I made a custom ProgressBar based on the one made by William Daniel: [How to change the color of progressbar in C# .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490884)

After doing some testing with lower percentage values I noticed this weird flicker:

[image: The weird black lines shouldn't be there]

I tried setting `DoubleBuffered` to true but they still show up.

Does anyone know why these weird lines show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not *flickering*, that's a form of *tearing*. The Custom Control is not always drawn completely; it can happen if you have a close loop that doesn't allow the Form to repaint itself and its child controls correctly.
Possibly, make the procedure that fills the ProgressBar asynchronous.

Some suggested modifications to *make it smoother*:

- Use floating point values for your calculations (don't cast to `int`), and use a RectagleF to define the bounds of your drawing.
- Remove the Bitmap and set [ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles):

  > If true, the control is first drawn to a buffer rather than directly to the screen, which can reduce flicker. If you set this
  > property to true, you should also set the `AllPaintingInWmPaint` to true.
- Then of course set **`ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint`**:

  > `AllPaintingInWmPaint`: If true, the control ignores the window message `WM_ERASEBKGND` to reduce flicker.
  > This style should only be applied if the UserPaint bit is set to true.
  > `UserPaint`: If true, the control paints itself rather than the
  > operating system doing so. If false, the Paint event is not raised.
  > This style only applies to classes derived from Control.
- `ControlStyles.Opaque` removes the background and lets [ProgressBarRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer) do its job, to fill the base graphics of the ProgressBar.

Calculate the current width of ProgressBar's colored parts based on the current `Value` set:
`float width = (this.Width - 3) * ((float)this.Value / this.Maximum)`
If **`width > 0`**, then paint the ProgressBar colors using the Forecolor and BackColor properties. Of course you could use a different set of properties to define these colors.

Add some anti-alias to the drawing, setting the [Graphics.SmoothingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode), to make the color transition generated by the [LinearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush) smoother. This is more useful when you set [LinearGradientMode.Horizontal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientmode).

Resulting in:

[image: Custom drawn ProgressBar]

---

```
public class ProgressBarCustom : ProgressBar
{
    public ProgressBarCustom()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
            ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
            ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle);

        float width = (Width - 3) * ((float)Value / Maximum);
        if (width > 0) {
            var rect = new RectangleF(1, 1, width, Height - 3);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, BackColor, ForeColor, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal)){
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a small improvement, you could draw a line 9 pixels in height, with a semi-transparent color, to the top side of the ProgressBar, to simulate the original *reflection*.
Change the code to add `Graphics.DrawLine()`:

```
// [...]
using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, BackColor, ForeColor, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
using (var pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(40, 240,240,240), 9)) {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 1.0f, 1.0f, width, 1.0f);
}
```

[image: Custom drawn ProgressBar + reflaction]

Comment: Had a bit of trouble with this at first since it seemed to make things worse. That was until I found that it's better to use `this.Refresh()` instead of `this.Invalidate()`. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: *At first*: and after that? -- If you have some problems with this implementation, post the code that uses it, so I can take a look and suggest how to fix it.

Comment: It seemed to cause a worse gradient and retain its tear, but this was probably since I invalidated the update rectangle every time the value changed. Refreshing it instead works a lot better and removes all tear.

Comment: I should work calling `Invalidate()` (asynchronous). If you call `Refresh()` (synchronous), you block the current operation (what triggered the `ProgressBar.Value` change) while the drawing is performed (not that it takes much, but...). So, you probably have a synchronous operation going on (note that the standard ProgressBar actually uses a Timer to constantly repaint itself, so it's an *improvement* anyway). You should try make your code asynchronous, everything will work better at all levels.